# Build number in each page of Inno setup

Tags: inno-setup

Inno Setup 5.5.7 changes default value of DisableWelcomePage to true to match [Microsoft's desktop applications guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742461(v=vs.85).aspx) - in order to reduce the number of user's clicks.
For me, the single important information on the Welcome page is the version and the build number of my product.

Indeed, the example by Microsoft shows the build number in the bottom lower corner - to the left of the "Next" button. How can I program this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`TNewStaticText`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses) to achieve that.

Simple example:

```pascal
#define MyAppVersion "6.3.129.200";

[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  StaticText: TNewStaticText;

begin
  StaticText := TNewStaticText.Create(WizardForm);
  StaticText.Parent := WizardForm;
  StaticText.Left := WizardForm.OuterNotebook.Width - (WizardForm.CancelButton.Left 
   + WizardForm.CancelButton.Width - ScaleX(1)); 
    //to position from left as CancelButton to right
  StaticText.Top := WizardForm.NextButton.Top + ScaleY(5);
    //to position same vertical position as ButtonText
  StaticText.Caption := 'Build {#MyAppVersion}';
end;
```

---

[image: Version in bottom left corner example]

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much. Is there a link describing all internal widgets of WizardForm except the list of classes in Inno documentation?

Comment: All information is in Inno Setup's Documentation - some examples go along with Inno Setup Distribution. All other things you would need to check up on web, like here on Stackoverflow. Btw. if the asnwer works for you, you can [Accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)